# How is the time complexity of the following while loop will be O(logn)?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, code-complexity

I did not understand how this piece of code will generate a complexity of **O(log n)**.how many times the statements inside the loop will work?

```
int a = 0, i = N;
while (i > 0) {
    a += i;
    i /= 2;
}
```

Comment: `i/=2`, which should be **inside** the loop (and not after the loop), reduces the input to half of it on each iteration, hence the complexity is log2 of the input.

Comment: Each iteration halves `i`.  So if `n` = 64, 6 iterations,.  If n = 1024 10 iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Let N=16, number of iteration is

```
i | loop
--------
16 | 1
8  | 2
4  | 3
2  | 4 
1  | 5
```

You can see **log<sub>2</sub>(16) = 4** and the number of iterations is log<sub>2</sub>(16) + 1. Or you can create a formulation for it
f(N) = F(N/2) + 1. Let suppose we have N = 2^K and so we have:

```
F(N) = F(N/2) + 1 
F(N) = F(N/4) + 1 + 1 
F(N) = F(N/8) + 1 + 1 + 1 = F(N/(2^3)) + 3
...
...
...
F(N) = F(N/2^K) + K => F(2^K/2^K) + K => F(1) + K => 1 + K
```

So if **N = 2<sup>K</sup> Then K = log<sub>2</sub>(N)**

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations of the loop is the number of significant bits in `N` because `i` is halved at the end of each iteration. Hence the loop iterates **log<sub>2</sub>(N)** times for `N>0` and none otherwise. Each iteration has 3 simple operations, an addition, a division and a test, so the time complexity is **O(log(N))**.